# How to wget a file with correct name when redirected?

Tags: linux, command-line, wget, redirection, curl

So after some time of searching on Google and Super User (and scanning man pages) I was unable to find an answer to something that (I think) should be simple:

If you go here:

```
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2340
```

And try to download the theme:

```
http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=9750
```

Like so:

```
wget http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=9750
```

You’ll probably end up with a file called `download_script.php?src_id=9750`.

But I want it to be called `molokai.vim`, which is what would happen if I used a browser to download this file.

What options do I need to specify for wget for the desired effect?

I'd also be ok with a Curl equivalent command.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

```
-O file
--output-document=file
```

> The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to file.
> If `-` is used as file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link conversion. (Use `./-` to print to a file literally named `-.`)

So,

```bsh
wget -O somefile.extension 'http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=9750'
```

**Or,** you may be able to get `wget` to **automatically** use the **filename proposed by the server** using the **`--content-disposition`** option if supported by your version.

```bsh
wget --content-disposition 'http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=9750'
```

Caveats as per the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html),

```
--content-disposition
```

> If this is set to on, experimental (not fully-functional) support for "Content-Disposition" headers is enabled. This can currently result in extra round-trips to the server for a "HEAD" request, and is known to suffer from a few bugs, which is why it is not currently enabled by default.

> This option is useful for some file-downloading CGI programs that use "Content-Disposition" headers to describe what the name of a downloaded file should be.

You can achieve the same automated behavior with `curl`, using,

```bsh
curl -JLO 'http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=9750'
```

`-O` uses the remote name, and `-J` forces the `-O` to get that name from the content-disposition header rather than the URL, and `-L` follows redirects if needed.

Comment: I should've specified that this needs to be automatic

Comment: As I understand it, wget relies on the web page to correctly inform it if the URL points to a file and it needs to be saved with something different, using the content disposition header, which wget may or may not fully support.  So you can't do it automagically with wget.  Curl may have more or less success depending on the web page.

Comment: the point is to be able to script these things without complicated parsing, curl is fine but so far i haven't been able to collect decent options for that either

Comment: So, running wget -S you can see the page does return a content disposition entry, Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=molokai.vim, which suggests it's not fixable.  wget just isn't coping.

Comment: Aha - I'm wrong, see updated answer.  This is why stackexchange sites work well - everyone learns something, even people answering the questions!

Comment: Nice one - easy tools are the best

Comment: Added the curl parameters that make curl work too.

Comment: This worked for me for the stackexchange podcast, which had been bugging me for a while.  Thanks.

Comment: `--content-disposition` worked well (at least it appears to be downloading the correct file as I type this), whereas `curl -JLO` did not do the trick. I'm new to using both tools, so I wonder why the disparity.

Comment: mg I love wget so much more than curl.

Comment: You may want to consider using `-R` with `curl` to preserve the original time stamp of a file, resulting in `curl -JLOR https://foobar.com/download`.

Comment: @rocksNwaves What happens if you use something like: `curl -JkLOvRC - https://wordpress.org/latest.zip` (not that I generally recommend downloading WordPress, but I just happen to know of that file as an example where it worked for me).  (I don't readily recall what all those options are, so, of course, it is wise for you to look them up first...).  May be able to then pipe to "tee -a output-file", then "grep content-disposition output-file | cut -d = -f 2 " to get the filename

Answer (score 96):

With wget you can do this:

```
wget --trust-server-names <url>
```

to save the file using the last file name the server gives you.

Comment: I wonder what the difference is between `--trust-server-names` and `--content-disposition`

Comment: Looks like `--trust-server-names` follows redirects to a different file, and `--content-disposition` names the file with the name specified in the response header without any redirecting required.

Comment: Why isn't this default functionality?!?!

Comment: @hopeseekr The server might be naughty and call the file .bashrc if you are not watching carefully. https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2012-04/msg00059.html

Comment: So helpful. I was downloading something and its name was download without any extestion. So bothering.

Comment: `--content-disposition` worked for Google Drive links for me, while `--trust-server-names` hasn't

Answer (score 5):

You could also use [aria2c](https://aria2.github.io) - it seems to work nicely with the Content-Disposition headers.

Answer (score 0):

Worked by following:

curl -o molokai.vim http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=9750

wget -O somefile.extension http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=9750

(changed case to smaller i.e. (the wget -O) to (wget -o)