# Get filename from a wget --content-disposition

Tags: bash, shell-script, wget

Inside of a bash script I am dynamically downloading a file and so I use `wget --content-disposition` to ensure the file names are correct, but how would I go about retrieving the name of the file `wget` saved it as?

Comment: Do you wanna look for filename while it is downloading or before downloading? İf you wanna see filename which server send you can type `wget --spider`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wget a file with correct name when redirected?](http://superuser.com/questions/301044/how-to-wget-a-file-with-correct-name-when-redirected)

Comment: @makgun, I would preferably like to get the filename while it is downloading. The intent is that I will do some processing on the file once it has completed the download.

Comment: Didnt you use progress bar? It has already indicator that shows file location and its name in progress bar

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to bash & pipes, how would I go about piping that output into another application (such as grep) where I can `grep -e` the contents?

Comment: Do you wanna pipe it on-the-go? Look for awk -W interactive NOT GAWK OR OTHER. I don't have time to write exact command but you can google it. Or before downloading use spider mod or use -O option to add specific filename

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way to do it with `wget` and `cut`:

```
wget -nv https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Golden_Gate_Bridge_0002.jpg 2>&1 |cut -d\" -f2
```

Explanation, `wget -nv ...` prints out something like this:

```
2016-11-15 14:58:44 URL:https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Golden_Gate_Bridge_0002.jpg [1072554/1072554] -> "Golden_Gate_Bridge_0002.jpg.22" [1]
```

The `-nv` flag on wget just makes it "non-verbose" (See: `man wget`)

Since `wget` writes its output to `STDERR` we have to redirect that to `STDOUT` before we can extract the text; to do this we add `2>&` at the end of the `wget`. Then to get out just the filename at the end I used `cut`. The `-d\"` is to specify that we are using `"` as a delimiter. The `-f2` specifies that we want the second "column", i.e., the data inbetween the first and the second delimiters `"`.

First column: `2016-11-15 14:58:48 URL:https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Golden_Gate_Bridge_0002.jpg [1072554/1072554] -> "`Golden_Gate_Bridge_0002.jpg.23`" [1]