# curl to get a file with correct name when redirected

Tags: curl

Following up on [How to wget a file with correct name when redirected?](https://superuser.com/questions/301044/how-to-wget-a-file-with-correct-name-when-redirected)
in which the answer says,

> You can achieve the same automated behavior with `curl`, using,
>
> `curl -JLO ...`

However, I found it not working for me for all cases, just like the comment to that answer. The `curl -JLO 'http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=9750'` works but not for another url, although `wget --content-disposition` works well for it. The failure log is enclosed below.

Is there workaround/fix for it?

```
$ curl -vJLO https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/
. . .
< HTTP/1.1 302
< Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Fri, 24 Jun 2022 20:24:57 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.25
< Location: https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=kg/apc/jmeter-plugins-manager/1.7/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.7.jar
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
. . .
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=kg/apc/jmeter-plugins-manager/1.7/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.7.jar'
. . .
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
} [5 bytes data]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7ffff39685c0)
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /remotecontent?filepath=kg/apc/jmeter-plugins-manager/1.7/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.7.jar HTTP/2
> Host: search.maven.org
> user-agent: curl/7.74.0
> accept: */*
. . .
> GET /maven2/kg/apc/jmeter-plugins-manager/1.7/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.7.jar HTTP/2

. . .
< content-type: application/java-archive
< last-modified: Mon, 20 Dec 2021 12:21:32 GMT
< x-checksum-md5: 5d625388a0fa18cc915dff7951dd1210
< x-checksum-sha1: 4fe37f9a091c35651177071f4bd442be85cbce0c
< via: 1.1 varnish, 1.1 varnish
< accept-ranges: bytes
< date: Fri, 24 Jun 2022 20:24:57 GMT
< age: 2093091
< x-served-by: cache-iad-kcgs7200079-IAD, cache-yyz4546-YYZ
< x-cache: HIT, HIT
< x-cache-hits: 1, 1
< x-timer: S1656102298.881078,VS0,VE2
< content-length: 906099
< 
{ [1034 bytes data]
Warning: Remote filename has no length!
* Failure writing output to destination
} [5 bytes data]
* stopped the pause stream!
  0  884k    0  1034    0     0   1659      0  0:09:06 --:--:--  0:09:06  1659
* Connection #2 to host repo1.maven.org left intact
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
```

Comment: Can you use wget instead of curl? This should work: `wget --content-disposition https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/`

Comment: @Subbeh, I already mentioned in OP that wget --content-disposition works. This question is on curl.

Comment: **The server is not sending any Content-Disposition header.** `wget` apparently falls back to the name in the (last) redirected URL, which is `jmeter-plugins-manager-1.7.jar`, but `curl` apparently uses the name in the original URL which is empty and fails. Using `curl -JLO https://jmeter-plugins.org/get` (with no slash at end) does work and produces file name `get` (admittedly not a very helpful name for this file).